# Mixing Instanced vs Non-Instanced data in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm having some difficulty mixing instanced data with non-instanced data.

What I have is an array of `GLfloat`s and an array of `GLuint`s.

The `GLuint`s is my index-data for rendering Elements. My `GLfloat`s is the vertex, texel and depth information.

What I'm doing is collecting all the data required for rendering a series of quads and them submitting them all at once:

- For each Quad there are:

  - Four vertices:

    - 2 floats for the vertex position
    - 2 floats for the texel position
  - One depth float
  - 6 indices submitted to the index buffer

They are in that order. So after one blit of a texture that I want to show all of it to the extents of the screen I would expect to see (stretch the whole texture to fit screen) (top-right, bottom-right, bottom-left, top-left) (texture coords may seem flipped but they're correct):

***Float Buffer***

```
[ 1 | -1 | 1 | 0 ] [ 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 ] [ -1 | 1 | 0 | 1 ] [ -1 | -1 | 0 | 0 ] [ 0.9 ]
[  pos   |  tex  ] [  pos  |  tex  ] [   pos  |  tex  ] [   pos   |  tex  ] [depth]
```

***Uint Buffer***

```
[ 0 | 1 | 3 | 3 | 1 | 2 ]
```

In case it's not clear, each of the four vertices for a quad are to use the same depth value in their frags.

And so, I setup the buffers like so:

```
uint32_t maxNum = 32; // this is the max amount I can submit

glGenBuffers(1, &m_vbo); // to store my vertex positions, texels and depth

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_vbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 17 * maxNum, nullptr, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

glGenBuffers(1, &m_indicesBuffer); // to store the indices

glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_indicesBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 6 * maxNum, nullptr, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

glGenVertexArrays(1, &m_vertexArrayObject);
glBindVertexArray(m_vertexArrayObject);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_vbo);
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 17, 0);
        glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 17, (void*)(sizeof(GLfloat)*2));
        glVertexAttribPointer(2, 1, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 17, (void*)(sizeof(GLfloat)*16));
        glVertexAttribDivisor(0,0);
        glVertexAttribDivisor(1,0);
        glVertexAttribDivisor(2,4);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_indicesBuffer);


glBindVertexArray(0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

And populating the buffers and drawing is like so. The `vertexAndTexelData` and `indicesData` are the `GLfloat` and `GLuint` buffers discussed above. `numSubmitted` is how many I'm actually drawing.

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_vbo);
            glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(GLfloat) * vertexAndTexelData.size(), vertexAndTexelData.data());
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_indicesBuffer);
            glBufferSubData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(GLuint) * indicesData.size(), indicesData.data());
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

        glBindVertexArray(m_vertexArrayObject);
            glDrawElementsInstanced(GL_TRIANGLES,indicesData.size(),GL_UNSIGNED_INT,(const void*)0,numSubmitted);
        glBindVertexArray(0);
```

When I draw all this, I'm getting a black screen. If I take out the depth data and the instanced drawing stuff, everything works perfectly fine. So I'm guessing it's to do with the instanced drawing.

If I put this through RenderDoc I see the following:

***Buffer Bindings***
[image]

So I can see my three vertex attributes appear to be set correctly.

***Vertex Attribute Formats***
[image]

So these appear to be in the right layout and the correct data types.

***Mesh Output***
However, if I look at the Mesh data being submitted...
[image]

Something is clearly wrong. The Depth values all appear to be correct, so it appears the instanced drawing is working there.

But obviously the positions and texels are busted. Interestingly, where there isn't a garbage value, i.e. a `-1`, `0` or `1`, it is correct for that position.

I suspect it's the stride or offset or something... but I can't see the issue.

Comment: I've managed to fix the issue by keeping the instanced data in it's own buffer. However, I'd still like to know if that's normal behaviour, or if I did something wrong initially.

Comment: The stride looks wrong. This should be the size of one vertex, not the size of one quad. I don't think you can store per-instance data interleaved like you try to do.